# Is $H= \{2,6\}$ a subgroup of $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)?$

Tags: group-theory

> Is $H= \{2,6\}$ a subgroup of $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)?$

**My attempt**: I think NO

By using this theorem(subgroup-test) :

> $H$ is a subgroup  of $G$ if $a-b$ is in $H$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are in $H$

Here  Identity is $0$

Additive inverse  of $2$ is $-2$

$$ 2-2=0 \notin H=\{2,6\}$$

Therefore $ \{2,6\}$ is not a subgroup of $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Is this true?

Comment: You are right. As a simple corollary of the theorem you use, you can see that the identity element always belong to a subgroup. So clearly $H$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: No need to invoke any particular test...your set is not closed under addition, nor does it have an identity element.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. No need to doubt. After $9$ years here at this site with abstract algebra you can answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It does not contain the identity, so cannot be a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

If $H \leq G$, then $H$ is closed under the binary operation $-$ mentioned in your theorem. But $$2-6=-4 \notin H.$$ Furthermore, $$e_{\mathbb{Z}} \notin H.$$ So (by subgroup criteria, DF), no $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.